# Batch file command for deleting all Audio/Jpgs in the directory, but excluding the Archive?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

At my company we handle a lot of audio and jpgs in daily batches. Inevitably this leads to hard drives filling up, and needs these files to be deleted, whilst retaining the batch's XMLs.

My actual knowledge of code is unfortunately minimal.

I was using the following:

```
del /S *.flac
del /S *.jpg
```

And to speed the process up, as the 'archive' folder expanded and took a long time for the batch file to go through, I changed it to this:

```
set "directory=D:(relevant directory)\Done"
set "excludeFolder=Archive"
del /S *.flac
del /S *.jpg
```

However, I can't tell if this is actually speeding up the process, as there's still a long pause, which would imply that it's stil searching my 'archive' folder.

EDIT: The solution suggested by Mofi was successful in achieving what I was after. Thanks all for suggestions!

Comment: Your two `set` commands do absolutely nothing to affect the `del` commands. All the set command does is assign a value to a variable.

Comment: You do know that you could have done that with a single command, don't you? ```Del /Q /S *.flac *.jpg```. BTW, excluding a subdirectory will likely increase the overall duration of the `del`etion process, _(unless that subdirectory is a large one and close to the top of the main tree)_.

Comment: The question describes the directory structure not detailed enough for suggesting the __optimal__ solution. The usage help of command __DEL__ output on running `del /?` in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window explains that multiple wildcards or file names can be specified on same command line. `del /A /F /Q /S "D:\(relevant directory)\Done\*.flac" "D:\(relevant directory)\Done\*.jpg"` searches __once__ in the entire directory tree of folder `D:\(relevant directory)\Done` for `.flac` and `.jpg` files and deletes them all.

Comment: If this directory contains a subfolder `Archive` which should be ignored for the deletion process, there should be used in the batch file as first line `del /A /F /Q "D:\(relevant directory)\Done\*.flac" "D:\(relevant directory)\Done\*.jpg"` without option `/S` and as second line `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\(relevant directory)\Done\*" /AD-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"Archive"') do del /A /F /Q /S "D:\(relevant directory)\Done\%%I\*.flac" "D:\(relevant directory)\Done\%%I\*.jpg"` to delete in all subfolders except subfolder `Archive` the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
:: Set variables for your Folders
set "directory=D:(relevant directory)\Done"
set "excludeFolder=Archive"  REM (SET Full Path)

:: Deny access to Archive folder
iCACLS "%excludeFolder%" /deny %username%:M
:: Use for loop to iterate throught file extensions you want to delete
FOR %%A IN (flac jpg) DO (
    DEL /s "%directory%\*.%%A"
)
:: Grant access to Archive folder once again
iCACLS "%excludeFolder%" /grant %username%:M
```

Remarks:

- Use iCACLS to deny access to Archive folder to ignore any changes to
  its files.
- Use FOR loop to Add file extension/s you want to search and delete in
  your directory.
- Use DEL /s to Delete desired files from all Sub-folders.
- Use iCACLS once again to grant access to Archive folder.

Hope this solution help you and if there is any further question, i will be glad to assist you.